# Home page heading

Tags: homepage, heading

I'm going to design a personal website with three pages: *About*, *Projects*, and *Contact*. Does the home page have to be "Home"? Can it be "About"? In other words, is it a right practice to have a website without a "Home" page? I want the users visiting *myWebsite.com* to go to "About" as my home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that following what users are used to is a good thing,

People are used to see the home page because it guides them, think of it like this:
when you enter at a big building for an establishment for example, first you'll see the reception area and probably a map telling you where you are in the building and how to reach other main parts of the building, I'm sure that the other parts of the building are more important than the reception area but this area helped them reach their goals more easily.

on the other hand, if you arrive at your friend's house you probably won't need a map for the small house and you can navigate it with ease or by the help of your friend.

and that's a website, if you have a big website that the user can easily get lost in, give them a proper navigation system and something more familiar to them

if you have a small website you can convert it to a single page website and guide them in they way you see fitting to the purpose of your website

Comment: "if you have a small website you can convert it to a single page website and guide them in they way you see fitting to the purpose of your website" I see what you mean. How about internal links or a table of contents on a single page?

Comment: I think internal links might be the simplest most straight forward way to do it, but table of contents seems interesting too!

Answer (score 0):

Having a web with three different types of information doesn't mean having three pages. Imagine the website of a newspaper with sections on current affairs, politics, entertainment, sports, etc. I think there is no newspaper website having each section on a different page. Well, the case raised in the question is exactly the same: the design is about a project website with three sections. The question of whether they should be on three pages or on the same page is a later choice.

You can look for some **POSTER-LIKE WEBS** where the entire web is on a single page.

Here some examples:

[nathan.tokyo](https://nathan.tokyo/)

There are even them with just one click action:

[peppasauce](https://www.peppasauce.love/)

Comment: "the design is about a project website with three sections." Not really: It's not about a single project. To clarify the content, on the _About_ page, I'm going to write a short bio, the _Projects_ page lists all my works, and the _Contact_ page shows different communication channels.